# Hibernate raises server validation error when doing AngularJS GET request

Tags: angularjs, hibernate, postgresql, rest

If I do a GET request with Angular, I get a 500 error.

```
var listAll = function() {
    var requestUrl = baseUrl + "/employee/all";

    return $http.get(requestUrl)
    .then(function(responseSuccess) {
        return responseSuccess.data;
    },
    function(responseError) {
        return responseError.data;
    });
};
```

Then I call the output function:

```
service.output().then(suc,err);
```

Problem is, I have to call `service` five or six times before a valid response is returned. All other times, a 500 Error is returned with the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate a newly established connection.
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:811) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:626) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:185) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    .
    .
    .
```

I'm using PostgreSQL as the database and a Spring based REST application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is that an explicit validation query is needed:

```
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

Hasn't produced this error since.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should check for missing connection.close() statements in the Java code. It's very likely that there is a connection leak, and randomly if the connections expire, they come back into the pool and it works.
2. There could be a genuine problem of connecting from the backend to the database. Check the network to ensure everything is fine.
3. It's possible that PostgreSQL is configured with not enough connections.

Comment: I have written all the code. Where should I add `connection.close()`? I'm using a `JpaRepository` extension. If it's any help, I'm using calls like `repository.findOne()`, `repository.findAll()`, `repository.save()`.

Comment: Also just opened application.properties and found this: `spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true`. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Hi, for now the issue seems to be solved by adding the missing line `spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
`. I'll update if I get the error again.